# How to make junit jupiter integration test aware of spring context?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit

I've defined `CompactDisc` bean in my spring application. According to [Spring TestContext Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-framework), `SpringJunit4ClassRunner` can make the following `junit-jupiter` integration test aware of spring context.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CdConfig.class)
public class CdTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;
    
    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }

}
```

But seems the `CompactDisc` instance was not autowired.

```
> Task :soundsystem:test FAILED

CdTest > cdShouldNotBeNull() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at CdTest.java:35
```

In `gradle.build` I use `junit` platform to run the test,

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events 'passed'
    }
}
```

Did `useJUnitPlatform()` overwrite the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` setting?

I tried with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, now it works.

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CdConfig.class)
public class CdTest {

    @Autowired
    private CompactDisc cd;
    
    @Test
    public void cdShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(cd);
    }

}
```

```
> Task :soundsystem:test

CdTest > cdShouldNotBeNull() PASSED
```

Anyone can explain why `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` failed?

Comment: that's because the `Runner` API is from JUnit 4 and your test should either use JUnit 4 *or* JUnit 5. This [article](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-unit-and-integration-testing-overview/) and especially the JUnit 4 vs. JUnit 5 pitfall might shed some light on this.

Comment: @rieckpil nice reference. It gave me some ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From `SpringExtension.class` document: `SpringExtension integrates the Spring TestContext Framework into JUnit 5's Jupiter programming model.`

So `SpringExtension.class` is for JUnit5 and `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` for JUnit4

JUnit5 (also called Jupiter) document [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-junit-jupiter-extension)

JUnit4 document [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-junit4-runner)